# Select the right group based on distribution/percentages from a table

Tags: c#, .net, database, csv

I have this CSV table

```
    filename,set,countrycode,timeofday,calibration,otherconditions,environment,precipitation,sky
    20130913_060749,NULL,AB,day,0.0773734454989712,,city,none,overcast
    20130913_060921,NULL,AB,day,0.289865800606369,,city,"none,haze",overcast
    20130913_060951,NULL,AB,day,0.288528490852974,,city,haze,overcast
    20130913_061021,NULL,AB,day,0.28358887059185,,city,haze,overcast
    20130913_061051,NULL,AB,day,0.190207839896071,,city,haze,overcast
    20130913_061156,NULL,AB,day,0.264707576215636,,city,haze,overcast
    20130913_071226,NULL,AB,day,0.206269488454271,,city,haze,overcast
    20130913_071256,NULL,AB,day,0.24887042174634,,"city,suburb",haze,overcast
    20130913_071326,NULL,AB,day,0.0938082719333332,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_071356,NULL,AB,day,0.00627162842767295,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_073510,NULL,AB,day,0.372935257761037,,city,"fog,haze",partlyCloudy
    20130913_073541,NULL,AB,day,0.328964273325638,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083611,NULL,AB,day,0.289816662996633,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083641,NULL,AB,day,0.291602099474152,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083711,NULL,AB,day,0.205089179739094,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083741,NULL,AB,day,0.345628858397651,,"city,playStreet",fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083811,NULL,AB,day,0.0755803723447712,,"city,playStreet",fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_083958,NULL,AB,day,0.322821196115,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_084028,NULL,AB,day,0.191182147849585,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_084122,NULL,AB,day,0.348537625962529,,city,fog,partlyCloudy
    20130913_094152,NULL,AB,day,0.331768750001122,,city,"fog,haze",partlyCloudy
    20130913_094222,NULL,AB,day,0.297051596076413,,"city,suburb",haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_094252,NULL,AB,day,0.430273879317406,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_094322,NULL,AB,day,0.294162675805556,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_104352,NULL,AB,day,0,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_104422,NULL,AB,day,0,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_104516,NULL,AB,day,0.518891257745526,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_114546,NULL,AB,day,0.50039745769322,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_114616,NULL,AB,day,0.275762545494949,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_114646,NULL,AB,day,0.483892784993604,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_114716,NULL,AB,day,0.352958331105499,,suburb,haze,partlyCloudy
    20130913_115640,NULL,AB,day,0.363986335968361,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_115710,NULL,AB,day,0.341002657474747,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_115740,NULL,AB,day,0.306984466792517,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_125810,NULL,AB,day,0.468337309183052,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_125840,NULL,AB,day,0.373136910552722,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_125910,NULL,AB,day,0.442251706279878,,suburb,haze,overcast
    20130913_125940,NULL,AB,day,0.473174240569349,,"expressway,suburb",haze,overcast
    20130913_150029,NULL,AB,night,0.0691816235557669,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150059,NULL,AB,night,0.0434565306952736,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150654,NULL,AB,night,0.277026709611307,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150724,NULL,AB,night,0.240319377418189,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150754,NULL,AB,night,0.209570896148148,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150824,NULL,AB,night,0.153044032648117,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150854,NULL,AB,night,0.276118705622896,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150924,NULL,AB,night,0.0274314977841365,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_151713,NULL,AB,night,0.424058516444064,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150824,NULL,AB,night,0.153044032648117,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150854,NULL,AB,night,0.276118705622896,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150924,NULL,AB,night,0.0274314977841365,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_151713,NULL,AB,night,0.424058516444064,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150824,NULL,AB,night,0.153044032648117,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150854,NULL,AB,night,0.276118705622896,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_150924,NULL,AB,night,0.0274314977841365,,suburb,fog,undefined
    20130913_151713,NULL,AB,night,0.424058516444064,,suburb,fog,undefined
```

I read it into a datatable and grouped them like that [with help from a previous question :_)] :

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   var oldRow = row.Field<string>("filename(hhmmss)");
   var newRow = oldRow.Remove(oldRow.Length - 4);
   row.SetField("filename", newRow);
}

var fileNameGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("filename(hhmmss)"));
```

I want to be able to select the group that fulfils a certain criteria(distribution) like :

Select 3 groups that fulfill having
30% day 30% night 40% dawn

PS: yes, the above table is not optimal for this but just the approach and proof of concept

Any similar "selection" examples,problem solutions are welcome

PS> Please look at the comments below :) there is more description

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement, however, here it is:

```
var fileNameGroups = tblCSV.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("filename(hhmmss)"))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Group = g, FileName = g.Key,
        DawnPercent = 100.0 * g.Count(r => r.Field<string>("timeofday")=="dawn") / g.Count(),
        NightPercent = 100.0 * g.Count(r => r.Field<string>("timeofday")=="night") / g.Count(),
        DayPercent = 100.0 * g.Count(r => r.Field<string>("timeofday")=="day") / g.Count()
    })
    .Where(x => x.DayPercent == 30 && x.NightPercent == 30 && x.DawnPercent == 40)
    .Select(x => x.Group)
    .Take(3);
```

Comment: your a legend man, Can I download your knowledge :P It is actually even more strange, its basically a camera test data, and that requires selecting from each day a certain distribution for each column. So  today I want 70%night and 20%rain, 30%X . next time i get something else. Is it less strange now ?

Comment: any idea of an example similar to what I mentioned :) ?

Comment: @user2708115: I don't know your _distribution_. But what is the problem? Couldn't you simply use three variables instead of `30`, `30` and `40`?

Comment: well, each row is a minute long file, it has various columns(attributes). I must select based on percentage like 30% day, 40% rain(weather column), 40% (any other column i.e. system)

Comment: so you see, at the above example its a good way to know how to do the linq expression, thanks for that.. but how do I select for instance 3 hours from a day based on multiple column distributions(%values). i usually have 1440 minute files(rows) with each having different values(lot in common) and i must pick 3 hours with certain distributions(percentages) to fulfil test data requirements and cover most of real world events. so from 1440 i can easily get 30% day and 70% night. but also columns x1,x2,x4 ? :(

Comment: so finally I can output the 3 hours (240 rows) that have the desired percentages for each requested value.

Comment: sorry but am really not getting any result here with the linqs .. no matter what percentage i change to :('

Comment: @user2708115: Sorry, i have currently not the time to support you. But i'm not suprised that you don't get a result since the `Where` is very restrictive. It selects only groups where the day-% 30, night-% 30 **and** dawn-% are **exactly** 40% without a tolerance or range. Maybe i can help you later.

Comment: Yes please when you have time, am stuck, my approach maybe not the best but you can get what I actually need. considering I have much larger data sets and interested in selecting hourly intervals and my percentage is actually not restricted per hour, its the total selection(ie. 3 hours that meet the overall criteria) i don't mean to hitch hike, I will keep trying and post if I got anywhere